Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't show up as a boot option
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my ssd and it doesn't appear as a boot option anywhere. No grub menu shows on boot, and my boot manager doesn't see Ubuntu anywhere. I can see the files on the partition through the live usb I created. Ubuntu doesn't show up anywhere on the bios or boot menu. I'm on an older Alienware Area 51 desktop if that helps.
